# data transmission from python to c++ using ctypes

Tags: c++, python, numpy, ctypes

I have c++ library, functions of which are called from python side. One of the functions gets a pointer on an array, which on python side has values in [0:255] and defined as

```
 seq1=numpy.array(image,dtype=numpy.uint8).flatten()
 seq=numpy.zeros((w*h*3),dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

the function call goes as

```
myCppFunction(ctypes.c_void_p(seq.ctypes.data),
                     ctypes.c_void_p(seq1.ctypes.data), 
...)
```

on C++ side the function defined as

```
void myCppFunction(ushort *seq, ushort *sequence1, ...)
```

When I simply print what I receive on C++ side as seq, sequence1, I'm getting values far above unsigned short range and zeros sequence is not filled with zeros.
Compilation goes fine but a real run results in segmentation fault. 
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Your first problem here is almost certainly what @WarrenWeckesser pointed out, that you're treating an array of 1-byte values as if they were 2-byte values. But on top of that, note that `ctypes.data` "may contain data that is not aligned, or not in the correct byte-order… may not even be writable." In other words, even if it were a `uint16` array, you can't just pass it to a `ushort *` without checking anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ushort` is 2 bytes, and `numpy.uint8` is 1 byte.

Comment: @Jaime: Sure it would. Imagine a very simple 2x2 image. So, `seq.ctypes.data` is an array of four `uint8` values: `[00, 00, 00, 00]` (in hex). When you interpret that are an array of four `ushort` values, it's `[0000, 0000, <random garbage>, <random garbage>]`. That random garbage is whatever happens to be next on the heap, which can easily be nonzero values. (Or, of course, it can go past the end of the allocated region and segfault.)

Comment: Are the first (w*h*3)/2 values zero?

Comment: @abanert Yes, I fully agree. My poorly expressed point was that you should still see **some** zeros.

Comment: you are right about the bytes mismatch, I have to change ushort on unsigned char (images correspond to numpy.uint8, so this has to be kept). Thanks